# Visual Studio 2012 XAML designer doesn't seem to update

Tags: xaml, view, visual-studio-2012, designer, blend

I seem to have a sudden issue with my XAML Designer view in VS2012, and a similar behavior in Blend as well. the view has stopped updating and I'm unable to see any changes immediately if I change any properties.

if I scroll or Pan, the Phone chrome seems to move but the content stays put. It gets restored upon slightly adjusting the borders or restarting the page. has anyone else faced this issue? do you know what I need to do? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional (Update 2)

this image will show you what I mean. I re-installed the app and it didn't help

[image: Scrolling the page is not updating the viewport]

Comment: Does this happen in all projects or just this particular one?

Comment: All Windows Phone Xamls, strangely not Win8 Xamls

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have ample virtual memory available?

Comment: I would think if Win8 XAMLs open up, this simple sample shouldn't suffer. I have 4GB of RAM on my laptop and no issue with paging.

Comment: The problem may also be with video memory. I know the Windows Phone emulator can be graphics intensive. It stands to reason that the designer will be, too. Maybe try increasing the shared video memory pool?

Comment: I could try that, will get back

Comment: I wouldn't count on 4 GB being necessarily enough, given the complexity of the XAML interface builder...

Comment: Any error in your XAML? Errors may block the designer from correctly working. How about the run time, I mean when running your app in the Windows Phone emulator. If this is only the problem in design time, maybe something wrong in the Phone SDK.

Comment: Doubt it, this is a fresh sample. Also, used to work properly a month ago.

Comment: I had the similar problem ones or twice in the near past - the fix was one of the obvious like reload Blend or reload this particular project or maybe restarting the laptop (with 4 GB RAM on board as well, btw) - sorry, can't remember particularly what helped then. But the symptoms were pretty much the same - stopped re-drawing surface after I've changed a few properties and the actual render rectangle was out of "phone frame".

Comment: Hi @JayKannan, just wonder if you have figured out a way to solve this issue? It's driving me nuts... :(

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the new Intel HD4000 drivers. if you revert to the old one it'll work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it.
I don't know which Graphics you have, but I have an Intel 4000 and a Nvidia 640m and I have to start Visual Studio with the Nvidia Graphics.
Maybe it's the same problem.

Comment: You maybe right! I have Intel 4000 on my Ultrabook, but I cannot change my drivers - I did update them recently, don't know if they're related.

Comment: Do you have only one graphiccard?

Comment: Yes ultrabooks have only one.

Comment: hm...sorry, but i think it's bug of the intel 4000 because if i start vs with it, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's defintely the HD4000 drivers that came out in March, revert to the older one and you'll be fine. someone needs to notify the blend team (if it still exists)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem when doing XAML design for Silverlight 5 app in VS2012. 
Have a HP 8570p with Intel HD Graphics 4000. Win7 64bit

I had the driver version 9.17.10.2867 released 17 Jan 2014. 
Had to revert back to 8.15.10.2712 released 22 Jun 2012 and it worked there.

Edit 2014-03-25: Reinstalled the newer driver(was going to test something and remembered this) and now it seems to work with the newer driver version.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put this as a comment on the question but that option isn't there for me... Not sure why.

I really don't think it's a memory issue. That doesn't explain resizing fixing the problem? Since this happens for you with all wp applications and not windows 8 I don't think its related to the emulator. I would try reinstalling the windows phone sdk and or the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight might be the faster options to start with.

Also a question, when you say all wp projects. Have you tried this with a CLEAN nothing added or changed project?

Comment: I re-installed everything actually. I've just stopped short of reinstalling Windows now. it's a problem with a brand new project as well.

Comment: I hate to say it but I guess the next step is an OS re-install. From your post it sounds like you didn't ALWAYS have this problem. If uninstalling silverlight and the windows phone sdk, and or vs doesn't help. I personally would do an os re install from scratch there are many issues noted on win 7 to 8 upgrades I mention this in case you were a win 7 upgrade. Install visual studio and the phone sdk first see if you have the issue then do your updates and other installs check the designer and see if anything causes it to break.