# I have issue about the design view of windows phone 8 in blend&visual 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

The issue is about the design view of windows phone 8 app (SDK 8.0 installed) in both blend and visual studio 2012 (updated pack 3).
According to the image provided, I'm just scrolling the screen for zooming as usual but the chrome layout is still being in the same place. 
(The Content e.g. grid - is correctly moved as expected). I needs to re-navigate to that screen to temporarily fix the issue.
Is there another ways to permanently fix this problem to me. I have already re-installed SDK, but the issue is still occuring.

Ps. For windows store app development, the problem is not shown up.

and i found this topic: [Visual Studio 2012 XAML designer doesn't seem to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509833/visual-studio-2012-xaml-designer-doesnt-seem-to-update)

but i have only Intel HD Graphic 5000 (MacAir 2013)
i cannot change my graphic card

Can anyone give me suggestions on the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Try**:

You can try turning hardware acceleration on or off. Under Tools -> Options -> General:
[image: Visual Experience]

Restart Visual Studio after changing these settings.

### **AND**:

Make sure you have the latest version of the graphics driver installed:

- [Intel Download Center for HD Graphics 5000 series](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=4th%20Generation%20Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A2%20Processors%20with%20Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics%205000&ProdId=3721&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39)